# How to parse and format strings out of irregular CSV in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv

I've scraped this allergy data string from a public website:

```
Cedar 679 gr/m3 High, Grass 20 gr/m3 Medium, Trees 80 gr/m3 Medium, Molds Low.
```

Sometimes the number of items is fewer, but the general format for trees and grasses is always like this, with commas separating each type of allergen:

```
TYPE AMOUNT g/m3 LEVEL
```

Molds is the exception; assume it will always be a string of text. Assume we don't require the molds data at all.

What library or technique would you use to parse this into a neat JSON object, for example:

```
{
   "Cedar": "679",
   "Grass": "20",
   "Trees": "80"
}
```

Comment: what would your ideal dataset look like at the end?

Comment: did you check https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser ?

Comment: I guess I could use csv-parser to slice each item into its own string, remove Molds, then split each string on a space to get the tree/grass and amount...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sam stated in the comments, it'd be ideal to utilize [npmjs.com/package/csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser)

However, if you want to use vanilla JS, I wrote a basic script that works given your input:

```
//function takes a csv string and returns a list of Objects
//and only includes values with 4 parts

function parseCsv(csvString) {
  let out = {};
  let spacedValues = csvString.split(/,\s*/);
  let values = spacedValues.map(str => str.split(" "));
  values.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (value.length === 4) {
      //you can change the value from an object to value[1] if you only need the amount
      out[`${value[0]}`] = {
        AllergenAmount: value[1],
        AllergenUnits: value[2],
        AllergenLevel: value[3]
      }
      });
    }
    // add an else if here if you want to keep values with more/less than 4 parts of the string
  });
  return out;
}


//wrapper that implements the builtin JSON.stringify method
const csvToJSONString = csvString => JSON.stringify(parseCsv(csvString));
```

To use it, just pass the csv string into the `csvToJSONString` function, and it will return a JSON string. You can also change the properties from an object to `value[1]` if you only needed the amount (commented in code).

Answer (score 1):

I worked with "csvtojsn" module before in a similar situation and it helped a lot.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson

Answer (score 0):

You should try [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) I'm using it in my current project and it works like a charm.